# Attempting to size grid tie solar system for 70 -80 kwh per day

Tags: solar-panels

Want to go grid tie mainly . (With a small back up I have already separate system )

I use less than 15kwh per day all summer max 70 kWh winter day. I can't build it all at once cost wise. I know the big part is inverter then add solar panels as I can afford . I would rather buy bigger cable to suite now than to small and have to up grade later , so if you know let me know please .

Basic location is London Airport Ontario Canada for solar reference south facing roof avail .

Any help you could give to size this would be of much appreciation along with the right size inverter .

Thanks in advance Phil

Comment: To be sure, you're asking about the size cable you need to run? From where to where are you looking for the run? How long a distance is it? We're going to need more details.

Comment: Look into a modern system with micro inverters at each panel, single large inverters are still available but you run into your issue of affordability, micro inverters eliminate some shading issues that can massively drop the system power when 1 or 2 panels are shaded, micros also allow for the system to be built in segments and the really great thing is no more massive conductors feeding the DC to the inverter, last that I will list if you loose 1 micro your system can still run but loose a single large inverter and the system is down until repaired or replaced.

Comment: What is the solar energy delivered per day in winter? 70kWh divided by energy delivered with efficiency of panels  will start to tell you what you will need.